# Is there a way to check if the 'wp_sitemaps_enabled' is true or false?

Tags: filters

I'd like to check if the `wp_sitemaps_enabled` filter is enabled or disabled. I've tried the following and it doesn't work i.e. the condition isn't met.

```
if( array_key_exists( 'wp_sitemaps_enabled' , $GLOBALS['wp_filter'] ) ) {
    // do something
}

if( has filter ( 'wp_sitemaps_enabled') ) {
    // do something
}
```

Is there another way of checking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `wp_sitemaps_enabled` filter is filtering the value returned by `WP_Sitemaps::sitemaps_enabled()`. You can get the global instance of `WP_Sitemaps` with `wp_sitemaps_get_server`, which means you can get the value of `sitemaps_enabled()` like this:

```
$sitemaps = wp_sitemaps_get_server();
$enabled  = $sitemaps->sitemaps_enabled();

if ( $enabled ) {

}
```